# Accessing log file in Codemagic

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, yaml, codemagic

I'm filling in the Codemagic yaml file to perform an iOS deploy for React Native. However, an error occurs while the builder is fetching the signing files:

```
Executing AppStoreConnect action fetch-signing-files failed unexpectedly.
Detailed logs are available at
"/var/folders/m7/aegaegawegaw323523t232/T/codemagic-09-01-22.log".
To see more details about the error, add `--verbose` command line option.
```

The error message is too vague. It simply tells me to use `--verbose`, which returns

```
[12:28:30] DEBUG > Load JWT for App Store Connect key 'NAME_OF_KEY' from disk cache
[12:28:30] DEBUG > Failed to load App Store Connect JWT from disk cache:
 Token is not cached
[12:28:30] DEBUG > Generate new App Store Connect JWT for key 'NAME_OF_KEY'
[12:28:30] WARNING > Executing AppStoreConnect action fetch-signing-files failed unexpectedly.
Detailed logs are available at "/var/folders/m7/aegaegawegaw323523t232/T/codemagic-09-01-22.log".
To see more details about the error, add `--verbose` command line option.
```

Which still is not enough for me to understand what's going on. My question is how do I access the Codemagic log at the mentioned `codemagic-09-01-22.log` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Codemagic you can access builder machine via SSH or VNC (https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/) to check all logs.

However from the log you provided are you sure you configured correct key name?

Comment: Thanks, friend. I changed the key name,  I wasn't sure if I should share it with the question.